# F# converted from R code fails to scrape data from web

Tags: r, f#

I am writing a F# program for scraping(or crawling) Korean stock market and do some analysis.

To get a data, I have to get a token from the API provider before.

Here is the R code doing so which works well.

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(readr)

gen_otp_url =
  'http://marketdata.krx.co.kr/contents/COM/GenerateOTP.jspx'
gen_otp_data = list(
  name = 'fileDown',
  filetype = 'csv',
  url = 'MKD/03/0303/03030103/mkd03030103',
  tp_cd = 'ALL',
  date = '20190607',
  lang = 'ko',
  pagePath = '/contents/MKD/03/0303/03030103/MKD03030103.jsp')
otp = POST(gen_otp_url, query = gen_otp_data) %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_text()
```

Referring to the snippets here: http://www.fssnip.net/a7/title/Send-HTTP-POST-request,
I wrote some code in F# to test whether or not the request works.

```
open System
open System.Net
open System.IO

type KRXQuery = {
    name: String
    filetype: String
    url: String
    tp_cd: String
    date: String
    lang: String
    pagePath: String
}

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let otpUrl = "http://marketdata.krx.co.kr/contents/COM/GenerateOTP.jspx"

    let krxQuery = {
        name = "fileDown"
        filetype = "csv"
        url = "MKD/03/0303/03030103/mkd03030103"
        tp_cd = "ALL"
        date = "20190607"
        lang = "ko"
        pagePath = "/contents/MKD/03/0303/03030103/MKD03030103.jsp"
    }

    let myCallback (reader:StreamReader) url = 
        let html = reader.ReadToEnd()
        html      // return all the html

    let queryBuilder (p: KRXQuery) =
        "?" + ([ 
            "name=" + p.name
            "filetype=" + p.filetype
            "url=" + p.url
            "tp_cd=" + p.tp_cd
            "date=" + p.date
            "lang=" + p.lang
            "pagePath=" + p.pagePath
        ] |> String.concat "&")
    


    let fetchURL callback url query =
        let target = url + (queryBuilder query)
        printfn "%s" target
        let req = HttpWebRequest.Create(target)

        // let postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (queryBuilder query)
        // req.ContentType <- "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        // req.ContentLength <- int64 postBytes.Length

        // //Write data to the request
        // let reqStream = req.GetRequestStream()
        // reqStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        // reqStream.Close()

        use resp = req.GetResponse() 
        use stream = resp.GetResponseStream() 
        use reader = new StreamReader(stream)
        callback reader url

    let otp = fetchURL myCallback otpUrl krxQuery

    printfn "%A" otp

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

But it fails to read the OTP token, returning an empty string(http content length is 0), which worked well in R.
And it returns HTTP 200 status code that the request somehow worked but only fails to read the token.

I've spent hours to debug this, but I failed so far.

I'd really appreciate your help!

Thank you.

Comment: Does it works if you browse it manually?

Comment: @Gus http://marketdata.krx.co.kr/contents/COM/GenerateOTP.jspx?name=fileDown&filetype=csv&url=MKD/03/0303/03030103/mkd03030103&tp_cd=ALL&date=20190607&lang=ko&pagePath=/contents/MKD/03/0303/03030103/MKD03030103.jsp
this is the link. And it works in a browser(I use safari).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and I was able to reproduce the issue. One problem is that you are not URL encoding the parameters and the R implementation does that. However, this still does not solve the problem.

The change to URL encode parameters is:

```
let queryBuilder (p: KRXQuery) =
    "?" + ([ 
        "name=" + p.name
        "filetype=" + p.filetype
        "url=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(p.url)
        "tp_cd=" + p.tp_cd
        "date=" + p.date
        "lang=" + p.lang
        "pagePath=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(p.pagePath)
    ] |> String.concat "&")
```

Does the service have some English documentation? Perhaps it requires some additional HTTP headers that R sends automatically and .NET does not...

Comment: Thanks you tried to solve this issue. I think you pointed a good mistake of my code. Unfortunately, I don't think they have a English documentation(probably since it is Korean stock market). And I figured out so far probably I have to put a http referer header sending data. I am still trying...